# Android Unfortunately, App Has Stopped On Navbar Back

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, android-virtual-device

I am using AVD to fiddle with making applications. I can run the app fine, but if I try to press the back button on the navbar, it brings me back (as intended) but also gives me the "Unfortunately, *app* has stopped." message.

So, how can I get rid of this? I have been frustrated with this for a long time and I feel like it's a really simple answer that I left out...

I am using an emulator. The (single) line of code it outputs in logcat when I press the back button on the navbar is this:

```
    03-28 14:47:46.391: A/libc(1707): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 1720 (Thread-117)
```

After it takes me back to where I was before I started the app, it kindly shows me an "Unfortunately, *app* has stopped" message.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you get a stack trace at the point of the "Unfortunately, app has stopped" message?

Comment: Please share some more log lines. The above log simply says a Segmentation fault.

Comment: No stack trace.. And the app still appears in the task manager for android, as well as being able to switch to it. That one line was the only line it output in logcat when the "Unfortunately, app has stopped" message came.

Comment: back button to go to the home screen or to navigate within your app?

Comment: would you be willing to post your code, there just not enouph info in your post to go at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to upload the code... And I somehow fixed the problem. I think that I fixed it by moving the declaration of the mGLView object in OpenGLES20Activity.java to the outside of the onCreate() method.

Makes sense because the object probaby got dereferenced since it was a local variable. Not sure why it worked until I pushed the back button though... The home button even worked without that message!

Apologies for not posting code first...